# Pandas select rows based on a function of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to learn Pandas. I have found several examples on how to construct a pandas dataframe and how to add columns, they work nicely. I would like to learn to select all rows based on a value of a column. I have found multiple examples on how to perform selection if a value of a column should be smaller or greater than a certain number, that also works. My question is how to do a more general selection, where I would like to first compute a function of a column, then select all rows for which the value of a function would be greater or smaller than a certain number

```
import names
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import random

def randomBirthday(startyear, endyear):
    T1 = date.today().replace(day=1, month=1, year=startyear).toordinal()
    T2 = date.today().replace(day=1, month=1, year=endyear).toordinal()
    return date.fromordinal(random.randint(T1, T2))

def age(birthday):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - birthday.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birthday.month, birthday.day))

N_PEOPLE = 20
dict_people = { }
dict_people['gender'] = np.array(['male','female'])[np.random.randint(0, 2, N_PEOPLE)]
dict_people['names'] = [names.get_full_name(gender=g) for g in dict_people['gender']]

peopleFrame = pd.DataFrame(dict_people)

# Example 1: Add new columns to the data frame
peopleFrame['birthday'] = [randomBirthday(1920, 2020) for i in range(N_PEOPLE)]

# Example 2: Select all people with a certain age
peopleFrame.loc[age(peopleFrame['birthday']) >= 20]
```

This code works except for the last line. Please suggest what is the correct way to write this line. I have considered adding an extra column with the value of the function age, and then selecting based on its value. That would work. But I am wondering if I have to do it. What if I don't want to store the age of a person, only use it for selection

Comment: Your function `age` does not work on Series. It seems to work on datetime objects. Try `peopleFrame.loc[peopleFrame['birthday'].apply(age) >= 20]`. Also you might as well define `today` once outside the function

Comment: Yes I know, that is exactly the question!

Comment: It's better to rewrite `age` function so it could be applied to the whole series. Then use boolean indexing.

Comment: @QuangHoang Could you elaborate what you mean by better. I am happy to sacrifice a bit of performance to write less code. If I wanted to write functions that work on the whole dataset and use boolean indexing I would use numpy to store my data. I thought the whole point of using pandas is to simplify SQL-like requests.

Comment: `series.apply` is essentially a for loop. It won't be troublesome if you have, say, few million records and you only run the function once or twice. Code-wise, your `age` function is somewhat equivalent to `(df['birthday'] - today).dt.year`.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Luckily, the data processing pipeline I am writing is limited by data analysis time, data storage and extraction is likely negligible. But it is good to know that pandas can be accessed by boolean index faster than a for loop, it might come in handy. Still, I think often a for loop is the most realistic solution. I frequently encounter functions that are too complicated to write with series-only operations

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
peopleFrame.loc[peopleFrame['birthday'].apply(age) >= 20]
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted :)